# Does CALCULATE need REMOVEFILTERS when the filter is on the same column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Assuming there is a relation between DateTable -> SalesTable, I want to calculate the Sum of SaleAmt in a modified filter context.

What is the difference between:

1. `CALCULATE(SUM(SalesTable[SaleAmt]),REMOVEFILTERS(DateTable),DATESBETWEEN(DateTable[Date],DATE(2021,12,14),DATE(2021,12,20)))`

vs

2. `CALCULATE(SUM(SalesTable[SaleAmt]),DATESBETWEEN(DateTable[Date],DATE(2021,12,14),DATE(2021,12,20)))`

In approach 1 I have used `REMOVEFILTERS(DateTable)`, where as in approach 2 I have not used this.

Answer (score 0):

Some functions and expressions when used in CALCULATE have built-in behavior to remove existing filters from their target tables.  I believe DATESBETWEEN is essentially equivalent to

```
calculate(
  sum(SalesTable[SaleAmt]),
  filter(
      all(DateTable), 
      DateTable[Date] >= DATE(2021,12,14) && DateTable[Date] <= DATE(2021,12,20))
)
```

Similar to how

```
 calculate(sum(SalesTable[SaleAmt]),month(DateTable[Date]) = 12)
```

is equivilent to

```
 calculate(
    sum(SalesTable[SaleAmt]),
    filter(all(DateTable),month(DateTable[Date]) = 12)
  )
```

So the REMOVEFILTERS behavior is baked in to DAYSBETWEEN.

Comment: Any reference documentation for this?